# MPI Scatter usage

Tags: c++, mpi

I am dealing with MPI programming and I don't quite understand how MPI_Scatter function works.

I'm calling scatter in master node, so do I need to call MPI_Recv in slave nodes after that?

So should it looks like this, or I'm getting it wrong?

```
int size;
if (node == MASTER){
    int arr[size * nproc];
    int sub_array[size];
    MPI_Scatter(arr, size, MPI_INT, sub_arr, size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    //do things;
    MPI_Gather(…);
} else {
    int arr[size];
    MPI_Recv(arr, size, MPI_INT, MASTER, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    //do things;
    MPI_Send(…);
}
```

Comment: Scatter is a collective operation, all processes in the group need to participate

Comment: What you describe in your snippet is the way the super olg PVM (Parallel Virtual Machine) used to work. But MPI simplified that and in MPI, all collective operations imply the same function call from all processes involved, irrespective of their role in the collective (should it be sending or receiving). So bottom line is: all processes should call `MPI_Scatter()`.